# Resaving files with little revision

Tags: android, filesystems

I am currently developing an app based on Android, however this question is more of a problem that relates to almost any type of the program developing.

My question is : Let's say your program or app saves a file, say a text file that says:

```
"hello hello hello world!!!"
```

and you save it. And one day your app loads that file and just add a simple character "a" within the original text file. Thus the text file has to save

```
"hello hello a hello world!!!"
```

then, if you want to save this changed file, is the app or program obliged to write the whole file from start to end again to save the revised data with so little change? I heard that modern file systems split the file into pieces at saving and reassemble them when loading by finding each piece of the file with some sort of an address table.

So, wouldn't it be faster to just rewrite the revised part and leave the other parts alone, and then when you load the file you just put the piece with the revised data in right place within the other pieces?

Comment: In general, yes, you would need to rewrite at least the part of the file after the first change. Please note that this question has been asked on StackOverflow the number of times and you will find plenty of answers by searching "write middle of the file" here.

Comment: Thanks I had no idea with which word to search